# Why Cassandra COUNT(*) on a specific partition takes really long on relatively small datasets

Tags: cassandra, nosql, bigdata, cql

I have a table defined like:

**Keyspace**:

`CREATE KEYSPACE messages WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;`

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE messages.textmessages (
    categoryid int,
    date timestamp,
    messageid timeuuid,
    message text,
    userid int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((categoryid, date), messageid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (messageid ASC);
```

The goal is to have a wide row time-series storage such that `categoryid` and `date`(beginning of day) constitutes my partition key and the `messageid` provides the clustering. This enables me to do queries like:

`SELECT * FROM messages.textmessages WHERE categoryid=2 AND date='2019-05-14 00:00:00.000+0300' AND messageId > maxTimeuuid('2019-05-14 00:00:00.000+0300') AND messageId < minTimeuuid('2019-05-15 00:00:00.000+0300')`

to get messages in a given day; it works so well so fast!

**Problem**

I need to be able to count the messages in a given day by substituting `SELECT *` above with `SELECT COUNT(*)`. This takes very long even with a little less than 100K entries in the column family; it actually times out on `cqlsh`.

I have read and understood quite a bit why `COUNT` is an expensive operation for a distributed database like Cassandra in [Counting keys? Might as well be counting stars](https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/counting-keys-might-well-be-counting-stars)

**Question**

Why would this query take so long even when:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages.textmessages WHERE categoryid=2 AND date='2019-05-14 00:00:00.000+0300' AND messageId > maxTimeuuid('2019-05-14 00:00:00.000+0300') AND messageId < minTimeuuid('2019-05-15 00:00:00.000+0300')
```

1. The count is on a specific partition with less than 100K records
2. I have only one Cassandra node on a performant Macbook Pro
3. No active writes/reads in the instance; less than 20 partitions on development laptop

Comment: The motivation for the data model is that messages for a single day for a given category are stored on one partition (on one node?); thereby the COUNT operation, I assume should not be scanning different nodes. There has to be something I don't understand

Comment: can you paste the exact query that you're executing?

Comment: @AlexOtt I have explicitly updated question with the query. Thanks.

Comment: As you only have a single node, the partition component really doesn't help/hurt (as all data is on the single node) - even though it's required. A few things you may want to look at: How many tombstones you may be encountering (You may want to look at the cassandra log to see if you see any warnings) and how many/large are the sstables. A count must complete where a SELECT * will only go up to the fetch size, which is why the SELECT * may work where the COUNT doesn't. There may just be too many rows to scan before the 5 seconds (LOCAL_ONE) passes. You could try LOCAL_QUORUM. You get more time

Comment: Thanks @JimWartnick for that insightful analysis. Indeed, I have warnings on tombstone threshold:

`WARN  [ReadStage-1] 2019-05-14 15:49:06,183 ReadCommand.java:569 - Read 5000 live rows and 10000 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM messages.textmessages WHERE categoryid = 2 AND token(categoryid, date) >= token(2, 2019-05-14 00:00+0300) AND token(categoryid, date) <= token(2, 2019-05-14 00:00+0300) AND messageid > 1224af0f-75c2-11e9-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f AND messageid < 3c8e4800-768b-11e9-8080-808080808080 LIMIT 5000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
`

Comment: @JimWartnick I have in fact solved the problem by eliminating what was causing the tombstones! 

I will go ahead and answer my own question from this finding. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is understandably caused by a [common pitfall](https://opencredo.com/blogs/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/) when the concept of 'everything-is-a-write' in Cassandra is overlooked and thence why tombstones happen.

> When executing a scan, within or across a partition, we need to keep the tombstones seen in memory so we can return them to the coordinator, which will use them to make sure other replicas also know about the deleted rows. With workloads that generate a lot of tombstones, this can cause performance problems and even exhaust the server heap.

Thanks to @JimWartnick's suggestion on possible tombstone related latency; this was casued by overwhelming amount of tombstones generated by my inserts that had `NULL` fields. I did not expect this to cause tombstones, neither did I expect tombstones to be a big deal in query performance; especially the `COUNT`.

**Solution**

1. Use default unset values in the fields when not present or omit them altogether in the inserts/updates
2. Be cognisant of the below facts as outlined by [Common Problems with Cassandra Tombstones - Alla Babkina](https://opencredo.com/blogs/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/)

> One common misconception is that tombstones only appear when the client issues DELETE statements to Cassandra. Some developers assume that it is safe to choose a way of operations which relies on Cassandra being completely tombstone free. In reality there are other many other things causing tombstones apart from issuing DELETE statements. Inserting null values, inserting collections and expiring data using TTL are common sources of tombstones.